# How to get the first instance of specific value found in data-* using jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

As the title states I want to get the first instance of a value that is given to the attribute in a data-*

Ex:

```html
<div class="row mt-2" data-group="1">
<div class="row mt-2" data-group="1">
<div class="row mt-2" data-group="2">
<div class="row mt-2" data-group="2">
<div class="row mt-2" data-group="3">
<div class="row mt-2" data-group="3">
```

Let's say I already have a list of all the unique values found in data-group. How would I be able to specify the divs that have the first instance of "1", "2", and "3".
The goal of this is to be able to prepend something before the first instance of each of the unique data-group using jQuery

Comment: Loop through the elements and compare the value of the previous item to the current item. If the values are different you know it's the first of it's type - assuming the values are sorted. If you're struggling with implementing that pattern, please add the code you've written to the question so we can help you debug it

Comment: Do you mean like `$([data-group="2"]).first()`?

Comment: @Lain are you sure I can access the data-groups like that? from what I've looked online they haven't done anything like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop over each `data-group` number, and select only the first one in the group :

```js
for (let i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
  $(`[data-group=${i}]`).first().css("border", "blue solid 2px")
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="groups"> <!-- or something -->
  <div class="row mt-2" data-group="1">Group 1</div>
  <div class="row mt-2" data-group="1">Group 1</div>
  <div class="row mt-2" data-group="1">Group 1</div>
  <div class="row mt-2" data-group="2">Group 2</div>
  <div class="row mt-2" data-group="2">Group 2</div>
  <div class="row mt-2" data-group="3">Group 3</div>
  <div class="row mt-2" data-group="3">Group 3</div>
  <div class="row mt-2" data-group="3">Group 3</div>
  <div class="row mt-2" data-group="3">Group 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Okay sweet, one last add on question. What would I do if this was all wrapped into a div

Comment: I wrapped it all in a div and it still works... Why wouldn't it?

Comment: oh lol mb for not making it clear, but If i wrapped it into some <div id=groups> or something. I'm very new to this js/jQuery stuff.

Comment: I wrapped it all in into a <div id=groups> or something and it still works... Why wouldn't it? :)

Comment: Fair enough, wasn't sure if you would then have to specify the id somewhere, thanks for your help!

Comment: The selector is only `data-group=n`, so it will select any element matching this pattern, regardless of any other criteria, class, parent or anything. If my answer solved your problem, please don't forget to mark it as accepted :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this with any string so you dont have to loop and use an iteration number.

This filters the jquery object that contain all `.mt-2` elements with the ones that don't have elements with the same data-group before itself.

`.prevAll()` gets all previous sibblings that match the given selector.

```js
$('.mt-2').filter((i, el) => {
  return !$(el).prevAll(`[data-group="${$(el).data('group')}"]`).length;
}).css('background-color', 'red');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<div class="row mt-2" data-group="some string1">1</div>
<div class="row mt-2" data-group="some string1">1</div>
<div class="row mt-2" data-group="some string2">2</div>
<div class="row mt-2" data-group="some string2">2</div>
<div class="row mt-2" data-group="some string2">2</div>
<div class="row mt-2" data-group="lalala">lala</div>
<div class="row mt-2" data-group="lalala">lala</div>
</div>
```